# How to get the updated values from the store with redux-form onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Using Redux-form 8.2.2, I want to update a **total** field whenever **amount** fields are updated in a FieldArray.
My `updateTotal()` function loops on the FieldArray and sums the amount values, which I fetch through `getFormValues()` or through a `formValueSelector`. But in both cases, the values contain the value before `onChange`, not after `onChange`. 
My component called by the FieldArray looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Field, getFormValues, change } from "redux-form";

const RenderTPP = props => {
  const { fields, dispatch, values } = props;

  const updateTotal = index => {
    let tppTotal = 0;
    values.tpp.forEach((item, i) => {
      tppTotal += parseFloat(item.amount);
    });
    dispatch(change("myForm", "total", tppTotal));
  };

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>
        {fields.map((tpp, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <Field
              name={`tpp[${index}].amount`}
              component="input"
              type="text"
              onChange={() => updateTotal(index)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </td>
      <td>
        <Field name="total" component="input" type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

export default connect(state => ({
  values: getFormValues("myForm")(state)
}))(RenderTPP);
```

With this code, when forEach reaches index, it gets the previous tpp[index].amount value instead of the updated one.

Temporarily, I am using the following workaround:

```
onChange={(event, newValue) => updateTotal(index, newValue)}
```

instead of

```
onChange={() => updateTotal(index)}
```

and

```
const updateTotal = (index, value) => {
  let tppTotal = parseFloat(value);
  values.tpp.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (i != index)
      tppTotal += parseFloat(item.amount);
  });
  dispatch(change("caseDataForm", "total", tppTotal));
};
```

for the `updateTotal()` function. This workaround seems to be doing the job, but it is not adapted to my situation, as I would like to call `updateTotal()` from other parts of my app. And even if this seems to work, I would greatly prefer to get the updated value directly from the store when `onChange` gets fired.

Comment: https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/883#issuecomment-215732308 This can help you. You should probably compare the values in a componentDidUpdate and call your function if changes were made or add a setTimeout around your updateTotal call

Comment: Thanks for the link and suggestion.
As my component is a functional component, I eventually used the `useEffect()` hook, with a `()=>{dispatch(...)}` as the first argument and an array listing the props to compare between re-renders as the second argument (this prevents an infinite loop).
I may also add a condition to avoid triggering the dispatch when the component mounts (as useEffect triggers after both mount and update), but that's not a big issue as for now.